# How to reduce my query cost

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Can I reduce my query cost?

Looking at the execution plan for this query -> Query 2: Query cost ( relative to the batch) : 93% and the only thing that sticks out is the "Hash Join Match (INNER JOIN)  Cost: 45%"

```
select t1.PrimaryKeyId, t1.AdditionalColumnId
from TableOne t1
    join TableTwo t2 on t1.ForeignKeyId = t2.PrimaryKeyId
    join TableThree t3 on t1.PrimaryKeyId = t3.ForeignKeyId
    join TableFour t4 on t3.ForeignKeyId = t4.PrimaryKeyId
    join TableFive t5 on t4.ForeignKeyId = t5.PrimaryKeyId
    join TableSix t6 on t5.ForeignKeyId = t6.PrimaryKeyId 
    join TableSeven t7 on t6.ForeignKeyId = t7.PrimaryKeyId
    join TableEight t8 on t7.ForeignKeyId = t8.PrimaryKeyId
    join TableEight t9 on t8.ForeignKeyId = t9.PrimaryKeyId
where 
    t1.isdeleted =  0  and
    t2.isdeleted =  0  and
    t1.startdttm >= @Begin_Date and t1.startdttm < @End_Date  and
    t1.paymentbalance = 0 and
    t8.pos_source_id in (select sit_source_id from @TableTen) and
    t2.transTypeId = 1 and
    t2.transitemtypeid in (1,7)


--- Table Counts 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableOne = 4014596
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableTwo = 5409514
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableThree = 552980
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableFour  = 552976
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableFive  = 4376
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableSix   = 4376
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableSeven = 9
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableEight = 175
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableNine = 36098
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TableTen = 68
```

Comment: create an index on isdeleted in tableone and tabletwo

Comment: Use SSMS to run the query, but before you run it tell it to show the actual Query Plan. Post a screenshot. Instructions here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1856/sql-server-query-execution-plans-in-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: Are your foreign keys all indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest an index on `t1(isdeleted, paymentbalance, startddtm)` to satisfy the `where` clause.  This will work best if only a few rows from `t1` are needed.

Hash matches are pretty efficient.  You can do index lookups instead.  So, also try these indexes:

```
t2(PrimaryKeyId, isdeleted, transtypeid, transittypeid)
t8(PrimaryKeyId, pos_source_id)
```

These will prevent access to the data for the tables.  The index "covers" the query.